# get all rows from mysql tables in json format

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel, d3.js

i have to set my json file  so i can display using the D3 JavaScript library  graph this is my code:

```
      <?php                 
          $mns = DB::table('mns')
           ->join('phases','mns.phases_idphase','=','phases.idphase')
           ->join('users','mns.users_iduser','=','users.iduser')
           ->where('projets_idprojet','=',$id)
            ->order_by('mns.created_at','desc')
            ->take(1)
            ->get();
           foreach ($mns as $mn ) 
             { 
                  $documents = DB::table('documents')
                   ->where('mns_idmn','=',$mn->idmn)
                   ->get();

                   $users = User::where('iduser','=',$mn->users_iduser)
                    ->get();

                   $phases = Phase::where('projets_idprojet','=',$id)
                    ->where('idphase','=',$mn->phases_idphase)
                    ->get();

        $nom_mn=$mn->nommn;
        if ($mn->etat=='initié')  $imagemn='http://localhost/batcoop/public/graph/mn_blue.png';
            elseif ($mn->etat=='validé') $imagemn='http://localhost/batcoop/public/graph/mn_vert.png';
            elseif ($mn->etat=='en attent') $imagemn='http://localhost/batcoop/public/graph/mn_gris.png';
        else $imagemn='http://localhost/batcoop/public/graph/mn_rouge.png';


        if(!empty($documents))
        {
 $table_corespond=0;
                foreach ($documents as $document) 
                {
            if ($document->etat=='initié') $imagedo='http://localhost/batcoop/public/graph/document_blue.png';
                    elseif ($document->etat=='validé') $imagedo='http://localhost/batcoop/public/graph/document_vert.png';
                    elseif ($document->etat=='en attent') $imagedo='http://localhost/batcoop/public/graph/document_gris.png';
                    else $imagedo='http://localhost/batcoop/public/graph/document_rouge.png';
          $arraydoc= array('name' =>$document->nomdoc,'image'=>$imagedo,'group'=>3);

                }

         }
        else
        {
        }
                foreach ($phases as $phase) 
        {
                $nom_phase=$phase->titrephase;
                if ($phase->etatphase=='initié') $imageph='http://localhost/batcoop/public/graph/phase_blue.png';
                    elseif ($phase->etatphase=='validé') $imageph='http://localhost/batcoop/public/graph/phase_vert.png';
                    elseif ($phase->etatphase=='en attent') $imageph='http://localhost/batcoop/public/graph/phase_gris.png';
                else $imageph='http://localhost/batcoop/public/graph/phase_rouge.png';

        }


        foreach ($users as $user)
        {
            $imageus="http://localhost/batcoop/public".$user->photousermin;
            $nom_user=$user->nomuser." ".$user->prenomuser;
        }

         $nodes = array(array('name'                              =>$nom_mn,'image'=>$imagemn,'group'=>0),array('name' =>$nom_phase,'image'=>$imageph,'group'=>1),array('name' =>$nom_user,'image'=>$imageus,'group'=>2),$arraydoc);

    $links = array(array("source"=>0,"target"=>1,"distance"=>6),array("source"=>2,"target"=>0,"distance"=>6),array("source"=>3,"target"=>0,"distance"=>6));
    $graph='{ "nodes":'.json_encode($nodes).',"links":'.json_encode($links).'}';
    $my_file='graph.json';
    $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates file
    fwrite($handle, $graph);
```

the problem is that i have more than one document and in my json file shows only the last document 
please can any one helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before line:

`foreach ($documents as $document)`

you should add:

```
$arraydoc = array();
```

and then change line:

```
$arraydoc= array('name' =>$document->nomdoc,'image'=>$imagedo,'group'=>3);
```

into:

```
$arraydoc[] = array('name' =>$document->nomdoc,'image'=>$imagedo,'group'=>3);
```

Comment: that did the trick thank u
but now th my json file become (invalid  with this code) those [ ] are the problem :[{"name":"\u00e9laboration.docx","image":"http:\/\/localhost\/batcoop\/public\/graph\/document_blue.png","group":3},
{"name":"11165846_1655090764725147_1845610795_n.jpg","image":"http:\/\/localhost\/batcoop\/public\/graph\/document_vert.png","group":3},
{"name":"chapitre1.docx","image":"http:\/\/localhost\/batcoop\/public\/graph\/document_rouge.png","group":3}]],